# Reading PDF in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, richtextbox

I want to read and display the contents of the PDF files into my RichtextBox. I am using windows application C#.  Is it possible?  What is the way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Adobe PDF IFilter Library](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=2611) to convert a PDF document to text.

Also see an example on the [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/pdf2text.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

[iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) is another alternative PDF library for .NET.

Comment: Does iTextSharp allow one to read PDF and convert it to RTF though?

Answer (score 2):

Since PDF is an binary format you'll have to use a pdf-library like pdflib  in order to read pdf-files.

[pdfLib](http://www.pdflib.com)

Answer (score 1):

You should checkout [PDFSharp](http://pdfsharp.com/) library and they have preview component, where else extracting text and showing them in RichTextBox could be little bit of more work, but you can try this.