# recursively getting files in a directory and read them

Tags: c#-4.0

I was wondering if anybody here could help me out as I'm still very new to C#. I have a drive with folders w/in folders  that all contain pdffiles. Is there a way to recursively loop through the files and read these files and write the data to a .txt file
I'm not sure how to implement this into my Console app--so does anybody have any code that might help?

i tried this prgrm but its throwing errors as "c:\anil not found as file or resource."

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\anil");
        FileInfo[] pdfFiles = di.GetFiles("*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (FileInfo pdf in pdfFiles)
        {
            Console.Write(ReadFile(pdf.FullName));
        }
        Console.Read();
    }

    public static string ReadFile(string destfolder)
    { 
        foreach(string file in Directory.Enumeratefiles(destfolder,"*.pdf"))
        {
            PdfReader pdfreader = new PdfReader(destfolder); 
        }
        string pdfText = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 1; i <= pdfreader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            ITextExtractionStrategy itextextStrat = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy(); 
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Filename);
            String extractText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, itextextStrat);
            extractText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(extractText)));
            pdfText = pdfText + extractText; reader.Close(); } return pdfText; 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: m having problem in Readfile method can any one help me with tat

Comment: Please don't cross post to multiple Stack Exchange sites. You end up causing messes like this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to

1. Walk the directory tree. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx) for an example.
2. Then [get the file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles.aspx)(s). You can rather use the `SearchOption` to search subdirectories.
3. Read the [pdf files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340278/reading-pdf-in-c-sharp) (stackoverflow will help) and write to the text file.

P.S: If you could give us more information, about what you've tried/or how have you approached this. You'll get more specific answers.

Comment: i tried this code but its throwing errors.....it should read all the pdf files in the folder and its subfolders

Comment: It would be easier to debug if you could put the errors as well.

Comment: "c:\\anil not found as file or resource." this is the error m geting after debug in th Readfile method

Comment: A complete trace would be helpful, but from what you mentioned, either the file does not exist or you don't have access to it. What does (FileInfo) `pdf.Exists` return?

Answer (score 0):

The error suggest that the folder `C:\anil` either doesn't exist or that the account that the program is running under does not have permissions to access it.

As for your code - several things stand out as possible issues.

You are treating the parameter passed into `ReadFile` as a folder, though you are passing in a *file name*, not a folder.

Your `foreach` loop will only work on the next line, as you haven't put everything you need to loop over in a code block `{}`:

```
  foreach(string file in Directory.Enumeratefiles(destfolder,"*.pdf"))
  {
      PdfReader pdfreader = new PdfReader(destfolder); 
      string pdfText = string.Empty;
      for (int i = 1; i <= pdfreader.NumberOfPages; i++)

      {
           ITextExtractionStrategy itextextStrat = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy(); 
           PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Filename);
           String extractText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, itextextStrat);
           extractText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(extractText)));
           pdfText = pdfText + extractText; reader.Close(); } return pdfText; 

      } 
  }
```

Comment: i had tried it but its not wrkng..........m getin error in PdfReader statement.. Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement

Comment: @AnilKumar - Did you debug through? What is the error? Do you have the right permissions?

Comment: yes i hve the right permissions....error is Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement  with this( PdfReader pdfreader = new PdfReader(destfolder);) statement

Comment: @AnilKumar - Did you debug through? Do you have a `using` statement you have not posted?