# How to read Text from pdf file in c#.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, pdf

I am working on one project where there is a functionality need to implement with PDF

I want to read the text of PDF file in my c#.net project.

Can anyone know what is the way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hve a look to the following links:

[How to read pdf files using C# .NET](http://jadn.co.uk/w/ReadPdfUsingCsharp.htm)

and

[Reading PDF in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340278/reading-pdf-in-c-sharp)

Hopefully they can guide you to the correct direction.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps pdfLib can be used.

From [pdfLib homepage](http://www.pdflib.com/download/)

> PDFlib TET PDF IFilter (Enterprise PDF Search on Windows) extracts text and metadata from PDF documents and makes it available to search and retrieval software on Windows.

Comment: You are also write, would like to give points on your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this library, very easy to use and exactly what you need:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14170/Extract-Text-from-PDF-in-C-100-NET

Comment: Thanks, right answer. How ever I got solution from fist link as well

Answer (score 1):

I would much like to use getText() method of PdfTextStripper.To implement this, you can have look over following url:

http://naspinski.net/post/ParsingReading-a-PDF-file-with-C-and-AspNet-to-text.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12445/Converting-PDF-to-Text-in-C

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, unless you are generating the pdf and are doing it correctly, no.

Pdf files are generated in a manner similar to what is sent to a printer. Not all text is readable in them, and the information about the text can be stored arbitrarily. Also some programs might save the text in vector or bitmap format.

Comment: Links posted are definitely useful but yes you correctly said not all text can be read. I have few PDF's which have 'vector text' in them, is there any library which reads those?

Comment: You would need to raster the pdf (turn it into images) then use some OCR software to read the text of the image. This will not be very reliable and will probably not scale. In short, not really.